# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when using Scrapy to crawl API

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to start on this page (https://api.pointsbet.com/api/v2/competitions/7176/events/featured), grab the key and append it to an event api (https://api.pointsbet.com/api/v2/events/) so I can grab some data from the event api and then loop through.

I am getting the error *TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable* and I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance!

```
import scrapy
import json


class PbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pb'
    allowed_domains = ['api.pointsbet.com']
    start_urls = ['https://api.pointsbet.com/api/v2/competitions/7176/events/featured']

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        events = resp.get('events')

        for event in events:
            eventKey = event.get('key')
            gameapi = f'https://api.pointsbet.com/api/v2/events/{eventKey}'

            if gameapi:

                yield scrapy.Request(url=gameapi, callback=self.parse)

                res = json.loads(response.body)
                fixedOddsMarkets = res.get('fixedOddsMarkets')

                for fixedOddsMarket in fixedOddsMarkets:
                    market = fixedOddsMarket.get('eventName')
                    outcomes = fixedOddsMarket.get('outcomes')

                    for outcome in outcomes:
                        name = outcome.get('name')
                        price = outcome.get('price')

                        print(market, name, price)
```

Comment: You likely try to loop through some structure in one of your `for` loops that is not assigned successfully before. Check whether `res`, `outcomes` 
or `fixedOddsMarkets` are correctly assigned, I would guess that one of them returns nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give a bit more information?
I see in your code at least 3 objects for iterations (`events`, `fixedOddsMarkets`, `outcomes`). Which one returns an error?

Error *'NoneType' object is not iterable* means that one of your .get() methods could not found an element. To avoid this error you can add the second argument into your .get() methods (it would be like `resp.get('events', [])`) or `resp.get('events', {})`. It depends on the stucture of your json (list or dict)).

But if you have some problems with connection to the api (or incorrectly assigned some json object as well) - it could not resolve your problem.

First of all, check if the response status code is acceptable (200, NOT 400, 403, etc.). You can do it with `print(response.status)` in your `def parse(self, response)` method).

If everything is OK, check json data that api returns to you directly in the code (you can do it with `print(resp)`).
If on this step you have appropriate json file from the api (and data is OK for you), check your code and json-file structure. `fixedOddsMarkets` or `outcomes` have to be incorrectly assigned.

---

As I understood, it tries to scrape 'events' from your gameapi link, right?
The problem is that you use 'self.parse' as callback argument.

Add another method, it should solve your problem:

```
def parse(self, response):
    resp = json.loads(response.body)
    events = resp.get('events')

    for event in events:
        eventKey = event.get('key')
        gameapi = f'https://api.pointsbet.com/api/v2/events/{eventKey}'

        if gameapi:

            yield scrapy.Request(url=gameapi, callback=self.parse_event)
def parse_event(self, response):
    res = json.loads(response.body)
    fixedOddsMarkets = res.get('fixedOddsMarkets')

    for fixedOddsMarket in fixedOddsMarkets:
        market = fixedOddsMarket.get('eventName')
        outcomes = fixedOddsMarket.get('outcomes')

        for outcome in outcomes:
            name = outcome.get('name')
            price = outcome.get('price')

            print(market, name, price)
```

Also, it is not a good variant to use `if gameapi` statement as it is always True. I think it is better to replace `if gameapi:` with `if eventKey:`

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding the second arguement in the get() method resolved the 'NoneType' object is not iterable error.

The issue I'm now having is that the the gameapi item isnt being followed and the subsequent items are trying to scrape from the original page.

The responses are all 200 so thats fine, and the when im printing the gameapi thats working so it must be the follow - does that look correct?

Comment: @GeordieFrost , try to add an another method. It should help you. For more information about how to do it, please, check my answer one more time. I has updated it just a minute ago.

Comment: Thank you so much Lawrence that has worked perfectly! Much appreciated!